# Recursive and Non-recursive SelectionSort

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion

This is a naive attempt of writing a recursive and non-recursive versions for `SelectionSort()`. My goal is mainly to present an elegant, easy-to-understand, **idiomatic** code, and therefore, performance is a distant priority. Please comment away!

```
// Find the index at which the minimum value 
// exists inside the Array 
function findMinIndex(a){
    return a.reduce((iMin, x, i, arr) => x < arr[iMin]? i : iMin, 0); 
}

// Remove the minimum value from the array 
// Return the value removed 
function removeMin(a){
    idx = findMinIndex(a); 
    minVal = a[idx];   // for [1, -5, 3], minVal = -5
    a.splice(idx, 1);  // [1, -5, 3] -> [1, 3] 
    return minVal;
}

// Selection sort, in recursive mode  
// As the name suggests, we select and 'splice' it 
// away from the array, and recursively 
// concatenate it to get the final result
function selectRecursive(a) { 
    if (!a.length) return [];   // terminating case 
    minVal = removeMin(a);      // remove the smallest
    console.log(v, a); 
    return [minVal].concat(selectRecursive(a)); 
}

var myl = [1, 2, 3, 99, 22, 55, 5];
selectRecursive(myl);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 [ 2, 3, 99, 22, 55, 5 ]
2 [ 3, 99, 22, 55, 5 ]
3 [ 99, 22, 55, 5 ]
5 [ 99, 22, 55 ]
22 [ 99, 55 ]
55 [ 99 ]
99 []
[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 22, 55, 99 ]
```

In addition, a non-recursive (*less intuitive* in my opinion) version of SelectionSort (using `push`, `slice`, `splice` and the `spread` operator) is presented below.

```
function selectionSort(a) {
  var length = a.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    a.push(  // select and append at the end
      ...a.splice(
        findMinIndex( // get min in a sliced 'a'
          a.slice(0, length - i)), 1) 
    ); 
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take this a function at a time before looking at your end goal.

```
function findMinIndex(a){
    return a.reduce((iMin, x, i, arr) => x < arr[iMin]? i : iMin, 0); 
}
```

The largest problem with this function is that it fails for empty arrays. `findMinIndex([])` incorrectly returns 0, an index which does not exist. If the array is empty, I'd suggest returning a flag value of `-1`.

Since `undefined` is less than `-Infinity`, we then have to swap the comparison around to make it work with essentially the same logic.

```
function findMinIndex(a){
    return a.reduce((iMin, x, i, arr) => x > arr[iMin]? iMin : i, -1); 
}
```

I would argue that this is still more complex than it needs to be. There is no need to use the `arr` parameter as we can just use `a` from the function call. (Some may disagree with me here) While we are at it, it improves the clarity to rename `a` to `arr`.

```
function findMinIndex(arr){
    return arr.reduce((iMin, x, i) => x > arr[iMin]? iMin : i, -1); 
}
```

Next up:

```
function removeMin(a){
    idx = findMinIndex(a); 
    minVal = a[idx];   // for [1, -5, 3], minVal = -5
    a.splice(idx, 1);  // [1, -5, 3] -> [1, 3] 
    return minVal;
}
```

How this works if pretty obvious, which is good. The one issue is that you create the global variable `minVal`. It looks like you missed a `let`. Some people would tell you to avoid functions which mutate their parameters, and while I generally do this myself, since this function is very clear about what it is doing it probably isn't an issue. However, I would probably rewrite this as a one liner, or just inline it as you did in your answer.

```
function removeMin(a) {
    return a.splice(findMinIndex(a), 1)[0];
}
```

Now for your recursive function. It also creates a global variable `minVal` but besides that looks good to me! Really nothing to say here.

The non-recursive selection sort could certainly use some work.

```
function selectionSort(a) {
  var length = a.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    a.push(  // select and append at the end
      ...a.splice(
        findMinIndex( // get min in a sliced 'a'
          a.slice(0, length - i)), 1) 
    ); 
  }
  return a;
}
```

Personally, I would prefer just simple for loops in this case. No need for all those function calls.

```
function selectionSort(a) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let iLow = i;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[iLow]) iLow = j
        }
        // Fancy destructuring to swap indexes
        [a[i], a[iLow]] = [a[iLow], a[i]]
    }
    return a;
}
```

Lastly, I can't help but mention `a.sort()` though I know that's not the point of this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

After I played around with `splice` a little bit more, I was able to refactor out the `removeMin` function completely. It seems like `splice` and recursive `SelectionSort` were made for each other! Of course, some may argue the code has become *less* readable, or has it really?

```
function selectRecursive(a) {
    if (!a.length) return []; // terminal case
    minVal = a.splice(findMinIndex(a), 1); // select and remove
    console.log(minVal, a); // to witness the magic of recursion!  
    return minVal.concat(selectRecursive(a)); // concat recursively!
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/coderdojo-coimbatore/thinking-recursively-with-code-afce0b8a3dc0 explains the 3-line code in detail.